# Having an issue with mouseup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Hello everyone I have this code working fine but I want the script to stop on the mouse up event.

Here is an example of what I have now.
How can I stop the script on mouse up event so that it looks like it only shows the coordinates when dragging over the image.

Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/Hc7x4/20/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#map-catcher").mousedown(function (e) {

        $("#map-catcher").mousemove(function (e) {
            $("#coord").text("x:"+e.offsetX+", y:"+e.offsetY);
              return;
        });

         $("#map-catcher").mouseup(function (e) {
          return;
         });        

   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using the mousemove event args**

I think the easiest way would be to check the event args for the mousemove event, you should b able to determine if the mouse button is down or not...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#map-catcher").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            $("#coord").text("x:" + e.offsetX + ", y:" + e.offsetY);
        }
    });
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eLfgT/)

NOTE: I am not 100% sure about the cross-browser compatibility of this method (tested in Chrome)

**Using a global flag**

If this doesn't work the way you want it to, you could try it with a global flag that ca track if the mouse is current down or not...

```
var moveMode = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#map-catcher").mousedown(function (e) {
        moveMode = true;
    });

    $("#map-catcher").mousemove(function (e) {
        //only set the coordinates when the flag is true
        if (moveMode) {
            $("#coord").text("x:" + e.offsetX + ", y:" + e.offsetY);
        }
    });

    $("#map-catcher").mouseup(function (e) {
        moveMode = false;
    });
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eLfgT/1/)

NOTE: This may cause some buggy effects if you release the mouse outside of the `"#map-catcher"` element. It might be a good idea to change the `mouseup` event to work on a `document` level instead. Like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    moveMode = false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed. I thought return would exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

Take your event bindings out of the mousedown handler. Furthermore, use .on() syntax, and If I were you I would use mousedown and mouseup to add and remove a class, that is bound to mousemove.

```
$('parent').on('mousedown', 'element', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('parent').on('mouseup','element', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});

$('parent').on('mousedown','element.active', function(){
    $(this).goCrazy();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you give me a code example. I am just new in the JS world.

Comment: if you just replace `on` with `live`, in case he manipulated the DOM

Comment: Providing the target element as the second argument mimics the behavior of live, more efficiently at that.